# Maven resources compiler: Failed to copy xx to yy: Couldn't copy xx to yy

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, build, compilation

Getting the following error during build/rebuild in Intellij v.2022.2.3.

`Maven resources compiler: Failed to copy 'absolute_path_to_module/src/test/test-resources/test-app-camel-settings.properties' to 'absolute_path_to_module/target/test-classes/.': Couldn't copy [absolute_path_to_module/src/test/test-resources/test-app-camel-settings.properties] to [absolute_path_to_module/target/test-classes/.]`

Tried the following but still getting the same issue:

- build and rebuild project/module
- mvn clean install
- invalidate caches and restart
- reverted all project changes to last time it was working

Was working earlier, only made normal code changes

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by deleting the old resources folder and creating a new one